# Correct use of "IS NOT" "OR" & "AND" boolean in nested ifelse

Tags: r, if-statement, nested, boolean

Want to create a column using ifelse based on five differing statements.

**Statements:**

1. If state = "N" **and** "region_1" **is**  "00" **or** "99", paste "region_2"
2. If state = "N" **and** "region_1" **is** NOT "00" **or** "99", paste "region_1"
3. If state = "T", paste "region_1"
4. If state = "3", paste "region"
5. If state = "W" **and** "region_1" **is NOT** "ED", "FL", "SG", "SY", "XP", "AL", "AG", "EB" **or** "AB", paste "region_1"

**Mock data:**

```
state = c("T","3","W", "W","W","W","W","N","N","N","Q","Q","N","Q")
region = c("CD","AB","IC","IS", "IE", "IF", "IA", "A2", "A9", "A9", "GW", "AW", "K0", "DW")
region_1 = c("DG","BC","CL","SY","ED", "FL", "AL", "23", "99", "99", "WB", "WD", "02", 'WW')
region_2 = c("00", "D1", "05", "00", "00", "01", "59", "00", "23", "24", '03', "03", "37", "03")

 a <- data.frame(state, region, region_1, region_2)
```

**My attempt to solve:**

```
library(dplyr)     
b <- a %>% mutate(t = ifelse(state == "N" & region_1 == "99" | state == "N" & region_1=="00" , region_2,          
             ifelse(state == "N" & region_1 != "99" | state == "N" & region_1 != "00", region_1,  
             ifelse(state == "T", region_1,                                                
             ifelse(state == "3", region, 
             ifelse(state == "W" & region_1 != "ED" | state == "W" & region_1 != "FL" | state == "W" & region_1 != "SG" | state == "W" & region_1 != "SY" | state == "W" & region_1 != "XP" | state == "W" & region_1 != "AL" | state == "W" & region_1 != "AG" | state == "W" & region_1 != "EB" | state == "W" & region_1!= "AB", region_1,
           NA))))))
```

**Problem**

Output has issue with `state == "w"` code. It's not  recognizing my attempted "IS NOT" and pastes `"region_1"` instead of `NA`(see lines 4:7). It's likely the same is happening for `state == "N"`,however, the conditions are not met in the mock data. Looking for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something erroneous in the last `ifelse` statement. You can simplify your syntax using the `%in%` operator. Based on the logic you provided I think the nested `ifelse` you're looking for can be expressed by:

```
ifelse(state == "N" & region_1 %in% c("99","00") , region_2,          
 ifelse(state == "N" & ! region_1 %in% c("99","00"), region_1,  
  ifelse(state == "T", region_1,                                                
    ifelse(state == "3", region, 
     ifelse(state == "W" & ! region_1 %in% c("ED", "FL", "SG", "SY", "XP", "AL", "AG", "EB", "AB"), region_1, NA)
          ))))
```

Hope that helps.

**Edit**:

In your last `ifelse` statement consider the first component of the logical expression:

```
 state == "W" & region_1 != "ED" | ...
```

In the fourth row of your data frame we have `state = "W"` and `region_1 = "SY"` therefore the above line will evaluate to

```
TRUE & TRUE | ...
```

The proceeding 'OR' operator can then discard the following statements (`...`) because the result of `...` doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what was required.

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be just missing the space in the not. You currently have region_1!= "AB" try adding a space so you have region_1 != "AB"

Comment: Still getting the same output unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

While it's roughly the same amount of typing, I prefer using `data.table`'s update-by-reference (`:=`) by updating a subset of the data each time. I find it neater and easier to read

```
library(data.table)

setDT(a)

a[state == "N" & region %in% c("00","99"), t := region_2]
a[state == "N" & !region %in% c("00","99"), t := region_1]
a[state == "T", t := region_1]
a[state == "3", t := region]
a[state == "W" & !region_1 %in% c("ED", "FL","SG","SY","XP","AL","AG","EB","AB"), t := region_1]

a
#     state region region_1 region_2  t
#  1:     T     CD       DG       00 DG
#  2:     3     AB       BC       D1 AB
#  3:     W     IC       CL       05 CL
#  4:     W     IS       SY       00 NA
#  5:     W     IE       ED       00 NA
#  6:     W     IF       FL       01 NA
#  7:     W     IA       AL       59 NA
#  8:     N     A2       23       00 23
#  9:     N     A9       99       23 99
# 10:     N     A9       99       24 99
# 11:     Q     GW       WB       03 NA
# 12:     Q     AW       WD       03 NA
# 13:     N     K0       02       37 02
# 14:     Q     DW       WW       03 NA

# setDF(a)   ## to turn it back into a data.frame
```